# type intersection not working as expected

Tags: javascript, typescript, generics, typescript-generics

with the code below, what i am trying to achieve is, i want to return fixed type (TReturn) from testFunction but additionally i want to be able to return whatever i pass to testFunction as argument in string format, so for the code below acceptable call should be

`testFunction({ foo: "x", bar: "", baz: "" }).baz.toUpperCase();`

```
type TArgProps = {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;
};

type Dictionary = { [x: string]: string | number };

type TReturn = {
  page: number;
  sort: string;
};

const transformer = (obj: any) => {
  let transformed: Record<string, string> = {};
  for (let key in obj) {
    transformed[key] = obj[key].toString()
  };
  return transformed;
}

const testFunction = <T extends Dictionary>(
  defaultProps: TArgProps & { [P in keyof T]: T[P] } = {} as any,
): TReturn & Record<keyof T, string> => {
  const transformed = transformer(defaultProps);
  return {
    page: 1,
    sort: 'abc',
    ...transformed
  };
};
```

but this returns an error

> Type '{ page: number; sort: string; }' is not assignable to type 'TReturn & Record<keyof T, string>'.
> Type '{ page: number; sort: string; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<keyof T, string>'.

why is that?

Comment: Because you're claiming that the object literal `{page: 1, sort: "abc", test: "1"}` can somehow have all the keys of the `defaultProps` argument even though it is independent of it?  If I call `testFunction({foo: "", bar: "", baz: ""})` the function return type says it has a `baz` property but it won't, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/w2pR1m).   Why do you expect that to work?

Comment: what about this? https://tsplay.dev/NB4gdW

Comment: That's not the same, is it?  If that's your question then please [edit] the code example to show it.  Depending on the use cases I might do something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbKX2W) but without a [mre] of your actual issue it's hard to know.

Comment: edited the question, in your example you are not passing the whole defaultProps to the transformer, which should be the case, and if possible it would be good that transformer returns Record<string,string>

Comment: You don't want `Record<string, string>` because mixing that with `{page: number}` would give a useless type (it's not `Record<string, string> & {page: number}`, since the `page` property would need to be `string & number`).  I'd think it's better to keep track of the actual keys passed in... like maybe as shown in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mAdG1N)?  Does that meet your needs or is it still missing something?

Comment: can you explain this part? Record<keyof T, {}> did you put {} because it can be any value?

Comment: I put `{}` because it can be any value *except* `null` or `undefined`, and since your code had `toString()` in it I needed to specify that it couldn't be `null` or `undefined` to avoid an error.

Comment: Side note: the question as asked is saying "why is this happening"?  Do you really want an answer to that primarily (which would be something like "when spreading a value of an index signature type, the index signature is dropped, see [ms/TS#27273](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/27273))? Or do you want to know how to make it work (which is what I've been trying to do in my previous comments)?  They're related but distinct questions and it's probably best for the post to make it clear which is the primary point.

Comment: i was hoping to understand what the issue was in the first place, but having a code demo, and knowing that key to fix this was in the transformer was equally helpful. i would be glad if you provided answer to the "why" question